# problem solving PDE: $u*u_x + u_y = -u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u*u_x + u_y = -u$$
$$u(0,t) = e^{-2t}$$

I tried solve with Lagrange and got 2 surfaces
$\phi(x,y,u) = x+u$ and $\psi(x,y,u) = y+ln(u)$ . when I used $u(0,t) = e^{-2t}$, I got a solution $$ u(x,y) = \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{1+4xe^{2y}})*e^{-2y}}{2} $$
but that seem to be wrong solution. I don't know what went wrong. your help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636252/analyze-u-t-u2u-x-cu-0-ux-0-gx/1638888#1638888) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636252/analyze-u-t-u2u-x-cu-0-ux-0-gx/1638888#1638888) for examples.

Comment: 1. I want to understand what went wrong here. 2. tried to solve it that way also,,, it got complicated.

Comment: $t=y{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: @martini, I don't see ... which line ?

Comment: On one hand you write $u(0,t)$, on the other $u(x,y)$...

Comment: $u(0,t) = e^{-2t}$ is the condition... without that condition I will have many solutions.

Comment: of cource, one can also write $u(0,y) = e^{-2y}$ if that makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving it with the method of charateristics, I obtained the general solution on implicit form :
$$\Phi\left(x+u\:,\:y+\ln(u)\right)=0$$
which is consistent with your result: $\phi(x,y,u) = x+u$ and $\psi(x,y,u) = y+ln(u)$

$\Phi(\phi,\psi)$ is any derivable function of two variables. An equivalent form is :
$$x+u=F\left(y+\ln(u)\right)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

So, the key point is the boundary condition $u(0,y)=e^{-2y}$

In $x=0$ we have : $$0+e^{-2y}=F\left(y+\ln(e^{-2y})\right) = F(-y)$$

This determines the function $\quad F(z)=e^{2z}\quad$ or any other symbol for the variable.

Puting it into the general solution gives :
$$x+u=e^{2\left(y+\ln(u)\right)} = u^2e^{2y}$$
Then, solving $e^{2y}u^2-u-x=0$ for $u$ leads to :
$$u=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4e^{2y}x}}{2e^{2y}}$$
This is the correct result because bringing it back into $\quad u\:u_x+u_y+u =0\quad$ verifies the equality.